# Copying existing function into memory buffer

Tags: c++, c, linux, posix

I'm trying to load a function into a mapped memory buffer and call it later so I've made a test case to try out:

```
auto func() -> void{
    asm(
        "nop;"
        "nop;"
        "nop;"
        "nop;"
    );
}

auto main(int argc, char *argv[]) -> int{
    void *exec_mem = mmap(nullptr, getpagesize(), PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE | PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE | MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0);
    // check errors here

    memcpy(exec_mem, reinterpret_cast<const void*>(func), 5); // size is known
    (reinterpret_cast<void(*)()>(exec_mem))(); // function call

    munmap(exec_mem, getpagesize());
}
```

Which works fine, but as soon as I try to do something even trivial I get a segfault.

I tried to do a simple variable assignment like this:

```
int x;
auto func() -> void{
    x = 5;
}
```

and now my function call segfaults. I have changed the buffer size appropriately and am certain the correct memory is being written into the buffer.

What important piece of information am I missing here? Why can't I do this?

P.S. Please don't lecture me on unsafe code, this is a simple personal learning exercise.

Comment: You must be very insecure in your job even contemplating writing this sort of code.

Comment: @EdHeal Yeah, I don't program for a job.

Comment: Just curious, what is this syntax: `auto / ->' ? Never seen it before.

Comment: @EugeneSh. C++11 trailing return type syntax. It's really trivial to use it in this case; I just randomly decided to use it haha

Comment: Anyway. A function might contain relative jumps to other memory locations, which are not copied. In addition, the size, which you say is known, is it really known? including the parameters handling and return code?

Comment: This stuff being done on embedded systems?  This feels like an OS access violation type issue - you know where you aern't allowed to modify code or run data type thing.  I've seen and written code like yours in very small systems for self modifying code, but not on systems with actual OS support.

Comment: What is the type of `void{asm("nop;""nop;""nop;""nop;");}` ???????

Comment: @EugeneSh. ah, relative memory locations! You should write that as an answer and I'll accept

Comment: @DieterLücking `void` is the return type and `{` is the start of the code block. `asm(...);` is just an asm declaration

Comment: Should I? ..Nah.. Too lazy.

Comment: @EugeneSh. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ fair enough

Comment: @MichaelDorgan It's going to be used on an embedded system, but I need a testing environment. Crazy enough, I'm actually building a CPU from scratch, writing a vm to simulate that CPU then writing a vm for that cpu in my vm!

Comment: Have you verified that your `func()` is exactly 5 bytes long by checking the generated assembly code. If it is any longer than that, due to function prologue/epilogue and/or optimizations, then you are only partially copying the function, and the random garbage past the end of what you copy might lead to some interesting effects, including segfaulting. But, as others have pointed out, that might be the least of your worries with code like that....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignoring the fact that this is blatant undefined behavior, if you do an assignment of a global variable, the generated code is likely to use [relative addressing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Addressing_mode#PC-relative_2) to reference the variable on some architectures.

That is, the function expects itself and x to be at a given address, and if you move it, things break.

This is what my GCC generates for your test function:

```
x:
        .zero   4
        .text
        .globl  _Z4funcv
        .type   _Z4funcv, @function
_Z4funcv:
.LFB2:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        movl    $5, x(%rip)
        nop
        popq    %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret
        .cfi_endproc
```

Note the `movl    $5, x(%rip)`, which means that the code uses its own address (stored in %rip) to compute the position of `x` and store 5 in it.

So in short, there's no simple way to do what you're trying to do, unless you make sure that your function only has [position-independent code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Position-independent_code). And even then, it's only asking for trouble.

Comment: You know a way to cause GCC to generate position independent code for a single function?

Comment: @CoffeeandCode you could put the function in its own file, and compile the file with -fPIC

Comment: Seems like a hassle, I'll resort to that if I find nothing. Thanks for the answer :) I understand the risks involved, but I need the desired behaviour and wouldn't use anything like this in any other project.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode You should look at a JIT library, maybe that's more suited to what you want to do?

Comment: I'm essentially making a JIT compiler, so you hit the nail on the head there. But I'm going to be moving this to an embedded system and need very few dependencies.